# Multiple DSLs connected to single HP server

Tags: networking, raid, virtual-machines, hp, dsl

Is it possible to plug 10 cat5 (network) cables that come from 10 different DSL modems to an HP server so I have 10 different broadband lines connected to one single server?

I want to use one of those internet lines for the main server and distribute the remaining 9 internet lines to 9 virtual different machines. So all virtual machines inside the main server have dedicated lines attached to them. It is basically like I have 10 different Operating systems which have their exclusive internets attached to them.

Is this possible technically? If so, how? Which server and what equipments do I specifically buy for this setup to build it inhouse?

My preference is HP servers. I want to add some 256 RAM and looking to run multiple SSDs on RAID so I can run all of them at once.

Comment: You're better off looking at converged networking and 10Gb connection. Then a pair of firewalls that will dedicate the connections to each vlan/vm

Comment: @MichaelLewis - erm...overdoing it a bit don't you think? why converged networking, the OP hasn't even mentioned any form of shared storage?? and are you assuming that each of these DSL lines are ~1Gb?

Comment: @Chopper3 Not at all, converged networking isn't the realm of storage only. It simplifies management, allows for easy expansion and growth, opens up lots of possibles without hindering anything else

Comment: @MichaelLewis - over normal 10Gbps NICs in a non-shared-storage scenario? How? Bear in mind I extensively use CNAs

Comment: @Chopper3 how what?

Comment: @MichaelLewis in a non-shared-storage scenario how does a CNA "simplify management, allow for easy expansion and growth, open up lots of possibles without hindering anything else" compared to a normal 1/10Gbps NIC?

Comment: @chopper3 well firstly you have a single card to manage at the host level. Over 10. Expanding the number of vms doesn't involve a new card each time. VMQ, offloading etc all performance better. Upgrading to shared storage will be simpler, but thanks for the discussion. Perhaps not best place for it though

Comment: @MichaelLewis - whilst all great technologies none of those are benefits over a normal 10Gbps NIC in a non-shared-storage scenario. Sorry just to make it clear - while I love CNAs I don't understand why you'd recommend a CNA, or even a 10Gbps NIC, in this situation as all of the traffic could easily be managed over a regular 1Gbps NIC - that's my concern, that your recommendation could be way over the top for this use case, even though it's all great tech. To be honest I don't think this user would get the difference either and almost certainly couldn't configure it anyway :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it possible to plug 10 cat5 (network) cables that come from 10
>   different DSL modems to an HP server so I have 10 different broadband
>   lines connected to one single server?

Yes, it's a terrible idea but yes you can.

> If so how?

Buy some multi-port NICs

> Any suggestions from geniuses in Networking?

A hint of sarcasm there but I'll rise above it - yes, here's a suggestion, don't do this like this at all, it's silly. Why do you think you need 9 x DSL lines? If this is for remote access are you expecting all bandwidth to be used on all lines all the time? Even if you really do need (or think you need) these nine lines why not connect them all to a single switch and connect the server to the switch via a single/dual normal 1Gbps NIC? If you need to segment them then just put each port into its own VLAN and trunk the uplink with .1q?

Of course this provides no resilience, you don't mention how important that would be.

In terms of server spec then sure HP's are great (the DL380 Gen9 is the most popular server in the world as it does 99% of what 99% of people need done) and although you don't mention which hyper-visor you're planning on using I'd imagine 256GB will be sufficient. Be aware though that HP doesn't support non-HP disks of any type, and we strongly advise you to not shoehorn your own disks into HP disk caddies - otherwise one day you'll be back here asking for data recovery and/or performance issue assistance (search the site for dozens of requests like this). But do make sure you use RAID of some form, and again we recommend here not to use RAID 5, its time has passed for dull technical reasons - try to stick to RAID 1/10 or 6/60.

Oh and one final thing - when you sign up to this site we put a bunch of words in front of your face, most seem to ignore them but some of those words state that this site is very specifically not for 'noobs' or beginners. You might wish to re-read that text.